# How i get the position of textcursor in QWebView Editable

Tags: qt, qwebview, qtextcursor

I I have an editable QWebView, and would like to get the position (QPoint) of TextCursor.
I searched but could only find the position of the cursor (mouse pointer)
webview-> cursor.pos ();
and this position is not what I want.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: So, what do you want? QPoint? Fine. Global? Local? Local to what widget? Perhaps you give a small explanation what you want to do. I can't think of any use case, which needs the QPoint position of a TextCursor.

Comment: So, I have an editable QWebView and accurate position TextCursor (Qpoint) in WebView to set as the center in implementing a ZOOM, like the WordPad (MS Windows).

Comment: I see. I don't think this is possible. QTextCursor is no graphical element with a defined position on screen. It is a logical position within a text. What you want to do is identical to find the screen position of the gap between two letters in a text. There is no easy function for that. Counting pixels using font parameters is probably far too complicated and error prone.

Comment: Well, when I implemented this type of ZOOM in a textedit was very easy to get the position, I used textedit-> TextCursor () to get the TextCursor and then I configured the the area cursor to get the correct position:
textedit-> cursorRect (textedit-> TextCursor ()). center
This command I returned to the center position where he was the TextCursor.

Comment: Bah, stupid me. Of course. Functionality like this makes sense in QTextEdit.

Comment: yeah, in qtextedit this functionality is easy, but now i'm using qwebview editable and was complicated.

Comment: webview->page()->inputMethodQuery(Qt::ImMicroFocus).toRect ().center()

Thank you for helping me!!!

Comment: You should make this a proper answer. No trivial question at all. I am sure others could get the same problem. I at least made myself a note with your solution.

Comment: @Greenflow I am still learning how things work around here. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved, to catch the QPoint TextCursor in editable QWebView is used:

```
webview->page ()->inputMethodQuery(Qt::ImMicroFocus).toRect ().center()
```

(for example: center() )

Thanks to those who helped me!